# Unable to log properly in log file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, lombok

I am using Lombok annotations (@slf4j) to create logs.

I have been trying to log in different levels such as log.info("processing xyz")
Log.error, log.debug but I am unable to log these levels into the log file.

Below is the log4j.xml file, only the request coming from the "client(postman/swagger) is logged and not the other things.

None of the level is working nor the info, nor error nor debug.

What might be the possible issue?

````
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="LogToConsole" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%t] %-5level %c:%L - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="LogToFile"
                     fileName="/Users/subhamsharma/Desktop/atm_log.log"
                     filePattern="/Users/subhamsharma/Desktop/atm_log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%t] %5level [%X{guid}] [%X{luid}] [%X{customId1}]
                    [%X{customId2}] [%c{3}:%L] - %m%n
                </Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
        <Async name="AsyncLogToFile" bufferSize="10000">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToFile"/>
            <blocking>false</blocking>
        </Async>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.apnatuitionmaster" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="AsyncLogToFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.springframework" level="error" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="AsyncLogToFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.apache" level="error" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="AsyncLogToFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.hibernate" level="error" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="AsyncLogToFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="springfox.documentation" level="error" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="AsyncLogToFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="com.mchange" level="error" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="AsyncLogToFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.elasticsearch" level="error" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="AsyncLogToFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="AsyncLogToFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>```
````

Comment: Have you excluded spring-boot-starter-logging and added spring-boot-starter-log4j2? The default logging implementation is logback

Comment: @JoshVandeWalle

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>